# Qual é a melhor performance em comparação de tamanho de strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho, memória

Qual a melhor opção a nível de performance?

E alocação de memória?

Utilizar a opção 1 ou 2?

```
String text = "ola mundo";
```

Opção 1:

```
If (  Strings.len(text) > 0 ) {}
```

Opção 2:

```
If ( text != "") {}
```

Comment: Opção 2 :  If ( text != "") {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro, não deveria usar `Strings.len()`, isso é algo usado na biblioteca de compatibilização com Visual Basic e, embora possível, não deveria ser usado em código novo, especialmente em C#. Não que ele seja problemático, apenas que mantém o uso de algo que não é o padrão. Use:

```
var text = "ola mundo";
WriteLine(text.Length > 0);
WriteLine(text != "");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Empty.cs).

A diferença deve ser pequena. Ambos acessam um dado muito básico. Algumas pessoas podem pensar que haverá uma contagem de quantos caracteres o texto tem, mas esta informação está disponível e não precisa ser calculada.

A segunda opção pode ser otimizada. Pode ser que a simples comparação das referências já indique que é igual e não precisa fazer mais nada (não acho que seja o caso neste exemplo, mas entendo que este exemplo não é bem o que deseja saber, ele foi usado só para simplificar).

Pode ser que a comparação do código *hash* da *string* já indique ser diferente, claro que se ele tiver que calcular o *hash* pode custar caro, por isso tenho dúvidas se ele faria.

Mesmo o caso pior quando ele compara o primeiro caractere já identificará se é igual ou não. Como de um lado só tem um caractere, o terminador, não precisa verificar mais nada. Estou falando hipoteticamente, não é assim que funciona na prática.

De fato podemos olhar o [código fonte da função que descobre a igualdade entre duas *strings*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,594) e ver que é ela faz o mesmo que a opção 1 (feito da forma adequada):

```
public static bool Equals(String a, String b) {
    if ((Object)a==(Object)b) return true;
    if ((Object)a==null || (Object)b==null) return false;
    if (a.Length != b.Length) return false;
    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

Dá para ver que há 2 ou 3 *branches* (comparações, a grosso modo) antes de verificar se os tamanhos são iguais, isso é um custo extra. Mesmo na verificação do tamanho tem que pegar o tamanho das duas *strings* e não apenas uma como na opção 1. É pior se usar uma comparação fora do padrão.

Note que estas questões são detalhes de implementação, então o que vale hoje pode não valer amanhã e depende muito da situação exata.

Embora não dê para afirmar parece claro que a opção 1 é mais rápida. Isto pode mudar ou pode ter alguma otimização que elimine o excesso de código da opção 2, mas na prática sabemos que isto não ocorrerá.

Não precisa olhar o *bytecode* gerado até porque ele nem sempre é um indicativo da real performance, a não ser quando é idêntico, o que neste caso não tem a menor chance de ser.

Se quer saber a diferença exata tem que medir, se só quer qual é mais rápido está aí a informação. Ela pode ser útil porque se a sua rotina for usada em um laço grande pode dar uma boa diferença de performance.

Nenhuma das duas opções alocam memória, então não faz diferença.

Comment: costumo usar o `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`, dá no mesmo ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis aí é diferente, se você sequer sabe se s *string* não é nula, não pode usar nenhuma das opções da pergunta, O fonte deste método é só `value == null || value.Length == 0`.

Comment: ok, acho válida a menção, normalmente se vai verificar se a *string* está vazia, é para trabalhar com ela depois, e um código assim geraria uma exceção: `string valor = null;
  if (valor != "")
  {
   string novoValor= valor.ToUpper();
  }` obrigado =]

Comment: @RovannLinhalis exatamente. Verificar direto só se tiver certeza que não é nulo, o que poderá ser possível garantir isso até pelo compilador no C# 8.

Answer (score 0):

Não acho que esse deve ser o tipo de coisa que alguém que está escrevendo `olá mundo` deveria se preocupar.

Se você realmente quer saber qual é melhor ou pior, o ideal é você olhar diretamente no assembly gerado. Lembre-se de colocar no perfil Release, caso contrário não terá as otimizações.

Outra idéia é usar ferramentas de profiling.